# tvOS - Manage Subscription Page

Tags: ios, objective-c, tvos, apple-tv, in-app-subscription

On iOS one can simply do:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://buy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/manageSubscriptions"]];
```

**Note:** Safari is not present on tvOS.

You can directly open the settings app with 'itms-apps'

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"itms-apps://buy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/manageSubscriptions"]];
```

Note: This will only work on device.

Question:

Can someone confirm the second approach will work on an actual Apple TV?

I do not have an actual device and this will not work on simulator.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling the following:

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"itms-apps://buy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/manageSubscriptions"]];`

on an AppleTV Dev Kit with TvOS Beta 3 results in nothing happening and getting the following message in the log:

> LaunchServices: ERROR: There is no registered handler for URL scheme itms-apps

Comment: Ever figure out how to do this? Looks like your post on the Apple forums also went unanswered.

Comment: Looks like "itms-apps://buy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/manageSubscriptions" opens the App Store landing page on Apple TV device. Doesn't work and give error in console in simulator "error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme itms-apps"".

Comment: Something to note: subscriptions aren't managed inside the App Store in tvOS (as of 12 anyway) - it's under Settings > Accounts > Manage Subscriptions. I haven't yet found a way to access that directly from an app. The clumsy way is to tell the user where to go in Settings...